# how to fix AzureAD post authentication issue with URLRewriting Middleware ASP.NET Core with .NET 6

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

**Error Message:**
An error was encountered while handling the remote login.

**Stack Trace:**

```
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync() at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Program.<>c.<<
$>b__0_3>d.MoveNext() in D:\AzureDevOpsBuildAgent\_work\986\s\ApplicationName\Program.cs:line 65 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

**Order of Middleware:**

```
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^(?!controller1|controller2|controller3)(\w+)/?$", "Controller2/Index?Id=$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var localzationOptions = services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localzationOptions);
}
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Controller2}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

This issue occurs randomly on the Production Environment and STAGE Environment but on DEV it works fine.
I have tried changing the order of the middle wares and tried to reproduce it on the DEV environment but it never occurs.
**I have no access to the STAGE or Production Environment.**

would appreciate any help.

Comment: You'd better provide more details about the pipeline definition if you run the processes in Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: Can you please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: I don't have any pipeline information because I don't have access to the azure. I'm just using development environment and unable to reproduce the issue. @BrightRan-MSFT

Comment: I will try to share the .csproj file but it is kind of confidential but it might not be possible for me @Harshitha

Comment: You can mask ur values and share

Comment: https://ufile.io/epulu2rt

Comment: Unable to open the above screenshot